# Travel insurance - need receipts for lost goods?

Tags: insurance

I signed up for World Nomads, a popular travel insurance. I noticed the fine print regarding lost goods states that "Items over $150 must be accompanied by original receipts.". But I've also heard elsewhere that you might be able to get by other ways to prove ownership: e.g. photo with you in it, credit card statement, manuals/box, etc... Original receipts are often not saved or never had if you purchased something used. **Do "World Nomads" *and other insurance companies* absolutely require original receipts or can other proofs of purchases be used?** If not, what are some things you can do to prove ownership and furthermore, ensure coverage for the amount you paid for your belongings (and not the appraised value)?

Comment: I've used WorldNomads with a photo and serial number before for an electronic item that was damaged. No problem whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have twice successfully claimed for items that I did not have any proof of purchase at all, so you should be ok with any sort of evidence that you purchased the item. Once was for an MP3 player ($200). The other time was for a phone ($400), but I had a letter from the service provider saying that I had reported it stolen and that it was blocked.

I think it really just depends on a case by case basis. Obviously, the more expensive the item, or the less believable that you would be travelling with it, the more evidence they may look for.

Ever since I had something stolen abroad I now just lay out my travel belongings before I pack them and take a picture of the whole lot. For electronics I take note of serial numbers as well. At least this way I'll always have at least some record that I owned and was travelling with the item.